# Update to EntityFramework 6 model isn't being reflected when WebAPI Controller is executed

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I have added a database view to SQL Server 2012. After this I updated my EntityFramework (v6) model, built and validated it. From the ASP.Net WebAPI (v2) project I removed and added the reference my EntityFramework library to ensure I was referencing this most recent update. The controller has all the correct links to the context and the EF model classes. No errors in referencing the updates I made from this GET method:

```
public IEnumerable<RTV_DedicationComments> Get(int EntryNum)
    {
        //var query = from c in context.RTV_GetAllDedicationsNames orderby c.DedicationName where c.DedicationName.StartsWith(Name) select c;
        var query = context.RTV_DedicationComments
                            .Where(d => d.EntryNumber == EntryNum)
                            .OrderBy(d => d.EntryNumber)
                            .Select(d => d);

        var results = query.ToList();

        return results;
    }
```

At runtime the following error is returned on the innerexception: 
{"Invalid column name 'PlatEntryNumber'.\r\nCould not use view or function 'dbo.RTV_DedicationComments' because of binding errors."} when the query is executed:

```
 var results = query.ToList();
```

'PlatEntryNumber' was from the database and EF model prior to the update ut it has been removed and it doesn't show as a field from dbcontext in the controller.

I turned on the SQL Server profiler to see if the query was executing there and it did:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Project1].[EntryNumber] AS [EntryNumber], 
[Project1].[CommentDate] AS [CommentDate], 
[Project1].[Comment] AS [Comment], 
[Project1].[CommentBy] AS [CommentBy]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[EntryNumber] AS [EntryNumber], 
    [Extent1].[CommentDate] AS [CommentDate], 
    [Extent1].[Comment] AS [Comment], 
    [Extent1].[CommentBy] AS [CommentBy]
    FROM (SELECT 
[RTV_DedicationComments].[EntryNumber] AS [EntryNumber], 
[RTV_DedicationComments].[CommentDate] AS [CommentDate], 
[RTV_DedicationComments].[Comment] AS [Comment], 
[RTV_DedicationComments].[CommentBy] AS [CommentBy]
FROM [dbo].[RTV_DedicationComments] AS [RTV_DedicationComments]) AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[EntryNumber] = @p__linq__0) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NOT NULL)
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[EntryNumber] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=5943651
```

What else can I check to remove the remnants of these database object references between the WebAPI and the EF?

Here is the entire stack trace:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232004
  Message=An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__a()
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__9()
       at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
       at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
       at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
       at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at RecWebAPI.Controllers.RTV_GetDedicationCommentsController.Get(Int32 PlatEntryNum) in e:\Development Test\RecTaxWebSLN3\RecWebAPI3\Controllers\RTV_GetDedicationCommentsController.cs:line 43
       at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
       HResult=-2146232060
       Message=Invalid column name 'PlatEntryNumber'.
Could not use view or function 'dbo.RTV_DedicationComments' because of binding errors.
       Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
       ErrorCode=-2146232060
       Class=16
       LineNumber=3
       Number=207
       Procedure=RTV_DedicationComments
       Server=mysqlserver
       State=1
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
            at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
            at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClassb.<Reader>b__8()
            at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TInterceptionContext,TResult](Func`1 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`1 executing, Action`1 executed)
            at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
            at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
            at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
       InnerException:
```

Comment: Have you tried returning a List instead of IEnumerable?

Comment: I am using IEnumerable is all the other Get methods and this one worked successfully prior to the fieldname change so I have not tried that.

Comment: Returning a List resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my WebAPI web.config file. The  had a tag pointing to the old database. This is somewhat confusing to me because I thought the EF handled all the connections to the database and therefore no need for the WebAPI to have the database info. It is working now.